# django IntegrityError (1048, "Column 'hotel_id' cannot be null")

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, modelform

I am new and this is my first question on this platform. am trying to add new rooms using modelform but am getting IntegrityError (1048, "Column 'hotel_id' cannot be null"). My code is as below. I appreciate the help

## models.py

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Hotel Name", max_length=100)
    owner =  models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE) 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Hotels"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = MoneyField(max_digits=65, decimal_places=2, default_currency='USD')
    number_available = models.IntegerField()
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # hotel = models.ForeignKey("Hotel", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Rooms"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_type
```

## views.py

Here is the view part to process the form

```
def new_room(request):

    if request.method=='POST':
        # hotel = get_object_or_404(Hotel,id =hotel_id)
        user = request.user
        if user:
            form=RoomsForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                newroom = form.save(commit=False)
                newroom.owner = request.user
                newroom.save()
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = RoomsForm(request.POST or None)
    return render(request,'newroom_form.html', {"form":form})
```

## forms.py

```
class RoomsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rooms
        fields =['room_type','price','number_available']
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The RoomsForm doesn't contain the `hotel` field, so `newroom.hotel` isn't populated. When you `save()` the instance Postgres complains about the missing value (ForeignKey [defaults to null=False](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#null)).

Since you probably don't want to allow rooms in unknown hotels you need to either include the hotel choice in the form or include the hotel id in your url (e.g. `/hotel/123/new-room/`) and set `newroom.hotel` manually.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the hotel id by using the below code

```
def new_room(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RoomsForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        rooms = Rooms.objects.filter(hotel__owner=request.user)
        for r in rooms:
            instance.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard')
else:
    form = RoomsForm()
return render(request, 'newroom_form.html', {"form": form})
```